# awk split with asterix

Tags: awk, split

I am trying to split a variable as follows. is there any efficient way to do this preferably using awk.

```
echo 262146*10,69636*32 |awk -F, 'split($1, DCAP,"\\*") {print DCAP[1]}; split($2, DCAP,"\\*"){print DCAP[1]}'
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '262146*10,69636*32' | awk -F '[,*]' '{print $1; print $3}'
```

or

```
echo '262146*10,69636*32' | awk -F '[,*]' '{printf("%d\n%d\n",$1,$3)}'
```

Output:

```
262146
69636
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a longer sequence you could try:

```
echo 262146*10,69636*32,10*3 | awk 'BEGIN {FS="*"; RS=","} {print $1}'
```